# How can I check if the oracle DB user account is in read only mode?

Tags: oracle

What is the difference between DB ready only mode and DB user read only mode? Please help me with the query.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between DB read-only mode and DB user read-only mode?

If the database is read-only (i.e. `startup mount` then `alter database open read only;`) then it is read-only for **ALL** users.

If a user only has only been given `GRANT SELECT` privileges from a tablespace then that user will only have read-only access to those tables but all other users will have access appropriate to their permissions (which may be read-write permissions).

Comment: Can you help me with the query for this point--"If a user only has only been given GRANT SELECT privileges from a tablespace then that user will only have read-only access to those tables but all other users will have access appropriate to their permissions (which may be read-write permissions)."

Comment: @Kishore Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74013025/edit) your question to explain what you are trying to achieve and what your expected output is because it is unclear what you expect a query to show.

Comment: I want to check if a user has been given GRANT SELECT privileges from a TABLESPACE

Comment: @Kishore - There is no such thing as `select` privileges on a `tablespace`.  You can look at `dba_role_privs` and `dba_tab_privs` to see what roles and object privileges a user has been granted.  But you'd need to potentially walk through several levels of roles (roles can be granted other roles in addition to object privileges).  And potentially differentiate between default and non-default roles or password-protected roles.